# Finding installed packages and the version

Tags: bash

I'm very new to ubuntu and I'm trying to find a command that tells what packages and the versions are installed on my "sandbox" I'm looking to bundle this as a output file

Comment: @serg Not a duplicate. That question is about apps accessible from the Dash (i.e. GUI programs). OP is asking about packages (which would include CLI programs).

Comment: @wjandrea still a duplicate , this has been asked before.  Just need to find the right link

Comment: Exactly where it is showing the version information as well or am I missing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question may be marked as a duplicate because you're expected to do some of your own research before posting on StackExchange sites. But, because the possible duplicate ([How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/295286)) doesn't touch on version info, here's your answer:

```
dpkg -l | grep "^ii" | awk '{print $2,$3}'
```

or

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2,$3}'
```

Decoded:

`dpkg -l` list all packages, including ones which have been removed.

`grep "^ii"` print only lines that start with "ii" (to exclude packages which have been removed, usually marked "rc"). Note that installed packages may not always be in "ii" status. This command will check: `dpkg -l | grep -v "^ii" | grep -v "^rc" | tail -n +6`

`awk '{print $2,$3}'` print the second and third columns (package name and version, respectively).

p.s. I wrote some comments about this before but my code was wrong.

Comment: FYI there's no need to pipe through both grep and awk - `dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/ {print $2,$3}'` should be equivalent

Answer (score 1):

I know you can use `dpkg --get-selections | awk '{print $1}'` to see all installed packages. but not sure about the versions i'll let you know if i find somthing else

Comment: `dpkg -l` will include version information

Comment: using that I keep getting a dpkg error saying unknown option -1

Comment: @Kenny It's easier to copy and paste instead of typing it yourself. That's actually an "L".

Comment: That would explain a lot lol.. worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Although selecting fields from the output of `dpkg -l` certainly works, the more fundamental `dpkg-query` command allows the output fields and format to be customized without resorting to additional text processing tools. As it happens, plain

```
dpkg-query -W
```

with no explicit format string gives exactly a tab-separated list of package names and versions (equivalent to `dpkg -l | awk '{print $2,$3}'`) as noted in `man dpkg-query`:

```
-W, --show [package-name-pattern...]
       Just like the --list option this will list all packages matching
       the  given  pattern.  However the output can be customized using
       the --showformat option.  The default output  format  gives  one
       line  per  matching package, each line having the name (extended
       with the architecture qualifier for  Multi-Arch  same  packages)
       and installed version of the package, separated by a tab.
```

If you want a prettier output more akin to that of `dpkg -l` you could use something like

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package;-25}\t${Version}\n'
```

to left-justify the package names in a field of width 25 columns, or

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${db:status-abbrev}\t${binary:Package;-25}\t${Version}\n'
```

to include the `ii` etc. status flags at the start of each line.